# why this simple example in this article throws error?

Tags: webservicemock

i have created all the classes in this link just to see how the Test mock working.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm

but i ended up in error when creating a test class and try to save it.

The entire classes that has been created,

Success:

```
@isTest
global class WebServiceMockImpl implements WebServiceMock {
   global void doInvoke(
           Object stub,
           Object request,
           Map<String, Object> response,
           String endpoint,
           String soapAction,
           String requestName,
           String responseNS,
           String responseName,
           String responseType) {
       docSampleComDocsample.EchoStringResponse_element respElement = 
           new docSampleComDocsample.EchoStringResponse_element();
       respElement.EchoStringResult = 'Mock response';
       response.put('response_x', respElement); 
   }
}
```

Success:

```
public class WebSvcCallout {
    public static String callEchoString(String input) {
        docSampleComDocsample.DocSamplePort sample = new docSampleComDocsample.DocSamplePort();
        sample.endpoint_x = 'http://api.salesforce.com/foo/bar';

        // This invokes the EchoString method in the generated class
        String echo = sample.EchoString(input);

        return echo;
    }   
}
```

Error:

```
  @isTest
private class WebSvcCalloutTest {
    @isTest static void testEchoString() {              
        // This causes a fake response to be generated
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl());

        // Call the method that invokes a callout
        String output = WebSvcCallout.callEchoString('Hello World!');

        // Verify that a fake result is returned
        System.assertEquals('Mock response', output); 
    }
}
```

Error Description:

Save error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Test.setMock(Type, WebServiceMockImpl)

What could be the issue here? i not even changed a single bit of code and did exactly what it has been given in the above article. But i do not know why i am getting this error.

Comment: What did you name YOUR test class? Is it the exact same name as in the example? If not, that's the cause of your problem as indicated by the error message (it can't find your class/method).

Comment: just updated the issue with all the classes

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If so I'll write it up as the answer.

Comment: as you see above the first two classes were compiled successfully. the test class only giving issue by throwing error...still getting same issue. i do not think there is a name mismatch which you referred in your previous comment...

Comment: Similar/same problem before http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31420/method-does-not-exist-or-incorrect-signature-in-test-setmock.

Comment: yeah..i did not have a chance to debug on that day...but still this issue persists...dont know what am i missing?

Comment: @KeithC I will delete this thread once i got some  suggestions here...