# Calling a webservice method from apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, webservices

I have a simple webservice method that updates Account Status from a custom Button in the Opportunity page:

```
Global class Backoffice {
    WebService static Integer  GenerateBackofficeTask(id  opId) {   
        Opportunity op = [SELECT AccountId from Opportunity WHERE Id =: opId];
        if(op.AccountId!=null)
            {
                Account ac = [SELECT Id from Account WHERE Id =: op.AccountId];
                ac.Type = 'Customer';
                update ac;
            }

    return 1;
    }    
}
```

Here the Test class i wrote:

```
@isTest 
public  class BackOfficeTest {
    static testMethod void TestMyContractWebService() {

   Integer x = 0;   
    Account ac = new Account(Name='testAccount1');
    insert ac ;


    Opportunity op = new Opportunity(Name='testOpportunity1',AccountId=ac.Id,CloseDate =date.parse('12/12/2014'),StageName='Evaluation');
    insert op ;
    system.debug(op.AccountId);

      x= Backoffice.GenerateBackofficeTask(op.Id);  
    }
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting the following error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   Backoffice.GenerateBackofficeTask(Id)

Please help me this that - I tried to find the reason with no success

Thanks in advance

Comment: The exact code you have posted compiles for me. If the actual code is longer, a common problem is having a local variable called `Backoffice` that hides the class name `Backoffice` - check for that.

Comment: I just tried it like Keith did, and the test class passed perfectly too.

Comment: Check this almost same post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31423 which has been answered by @KeithC Looks like you are having same issue